# Как передать переменную в параметр BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, bs4

Если написать параметр напрямую:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def get_currency_today():
    resp = requests.get("http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp")
    soap = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, "xml")
    currency = soap.find("CharCode", text="TRY")
    print(currency)
get_currency_today()
```

То выдает результат:

```
<CharCode>TRY</CharCode>
```

Если хочу передать переменную в качестве параметра к text таким образом:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def get_currency_today():
    county_currency = "'TRY'"
    resp = requests.get("http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp")
    soap = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, "xml")
    currency = soap.find("CharCode", text=county_currency)
    print(currency)
get_currency_today()
```

То в результате выдает:

```
None
```

Как можно передать county_currency, что бы результат был TRY?

Comment: место `county_currency = "'TRY'"` напишите `county_currency = "TRY"`

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю вариант через цикл и поиск значения по названию валюты.

Из-за структуры данных, думаю, это самое простое решение:

```
<ValCurs Date="19.01.2021" name="Foreign Currency Market">
    <Valute ID="R01010">
        <NumCode>036</NumCode>
        <CharCode>AUD</CharCode>
        <Nominal>1</Nominal>
        <Name>Австралийский доллар</Name>
        <Value>56,7525</Value>
    </Valute>
    ...
```

Пример:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def get_currency_today(char_code="USD"):
    rs = requests.get("http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp")
    root = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, "xml")
    for valute in root.find_all("Valute"):
        if valute.find('CharCode', text=char_code):
            return valute.find('Value').text

print(get_currency_today())
# 73,9735

print(get_currency_today('TRY'))
# 98,3076
```